# Adding an image as accessory view in UITableViewCell is not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

i am trying to add some labels and images as accessory view in UITableViewCell.
But it is not showing in table cell my code is

```
unsigned int flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents* parts = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:[NSDate date]];

UILabel *lbTime = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-80, -21, 99, 20)];
[lbTime setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[lbTime setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[lbTime setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
int hour = parts.hour;
NSString *amPm = @"Am";
if (hour>12) {
    hour = hour -12;
    amPm = @"Pm";
}
lbTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02d:%.02d %@",hour,parts.minute,amPm];


UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgWhiteAero.png"];
cell.accessoryView = imgView;


UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]init];
[view addSubview:lbTime];
[view addSubview:imgView];
cell.accessoryView = view;
[view release];
[imgView release];
```

label is showing successfully but image is not
when i add only image as accessory view it becomes visible 
    cell.accessoryView = imgView;

but when i add it in a UIView like above mentioned code it is not showing

Comment: set the view frame and let me know is it working or not?

Comment: Hey dude you are setting this cell.accessoryView two times dude and set the frame for the view

Comment: i set it but no success

Comment: See if your image imgWhiteAero.png is correctly spelled or available..

Comment: Manohar you are right please write your answer in "Answer Section" so that i can mark it right

Comment: [view addSubview:imgView]; this code it add img view in view\

Comment: first remove this line `cell.accessoryView = imgView;` you are setting your accessoryView twice.